# Is it possible to make a checkered table in Ember.js using ONLY Handlebars and ember-composable-helpers

Tags: javascript, ember.js, bootstrap-4, handlebars.js, frontend

I'm new to Ember.js and I'm trying to make a simple checkered table.  I'm using Bootstrap 4, ember-composable-helpers, and Handlebars.  I want to know if anyone knows how to do this WITHOUT using javascript?

My mockup code is as follows however I don't know how to insert logic into the #if HBS helper:

```
<h1>Table</h1>
<table class="w-100">
    {{#each (range 0 5) as |row|}}
    <tr class="">
        {{#each (range 0 5) as |cell|}}
{{!-- HOW DO I GIVE A TRUTHY VALUE FOR CELL == 1??? --}}
            {{#if cell == 1 }}
                <td class="bg-dark">{{cell}}</td>
            {{/if }}
        {{/each}}
    </tr>
    {{/each}}
</table>
```

Should I just make a ternary class? How would I do this?

Comment: Hi! Can you share more about why you don't want to use any JavaScript for this? It seems like writing an "equals" helper of your own would work really well here. https://guides.emberjs.com/release/templates/writing-helpers/

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't want to write any JavaScript, I think your main option is to install and use [ember-truth-helpers](https://github.com/jmurphyau/ember-truth-helpers):

```sh
ember install ember-truth-helpers
```

```
<h1>Table</h1>
<table class="w-100">
    {{#each (range 0 5) as |row|}}
    <tr class="">
        {{#each (range 0 5) as |cell|}}
{{!-- HOW DO I GIVE A TRUTHY VALUE FOR CELL == 1??? --}}
            {{#if (eq cell 1) }}
                <td class="bg-dark">{{cell}}</td>
            {{/if }}
        {{/each}}
    </tr>
    {{/each}}
</table>
```

I recommend joining [Ember Discord](https://emberjs.com/community/) if you have any general questions as you are learning Ember. Good luck!